# Duplicate data on multiple clicks using random token check Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, server-side

I have a form where I am adding some data to db, but I want to avoid duplicate records if user clicks multiple times on the button, I can disable the button using JS but I want to have some checking on server side as well.

Currently on form I am setting a session variable with random number and sending it to controller using textbox (hidden) and then in controller I check if session variable is equal to textbox then add to db - but still the data adds multiple time in db, would appreciate if someone could help. Thanks.

Controller:

```
if ($request->token == session('test')){
    session()->forget('test');
    sleep(20); (this i added in order to test)
    TableName::create([
        'code' => 'test',
        'name' => 'testing',
    ]);
    return "done";
} else {
    return "stopped";
}
```

Blade:

```
{{session(['test'=> rand()])}}
<input type="text" value="{{session('test')}}" name="token">
```

Comment: when there is a single click, disable the button via javascript

Comment: You can create hash to precheck input in your sql or if it's a must, change your column to unique to avoid duplicates.

Comment: if you are using laravel yung can use `unique` function on your validation controller

Comment: set unique key on that column will help a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods in Laravel **firstOrCreate** or **firstOrNew**.

Refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

The firstOrNew method, like firstOrCreate will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned

```
// Retrieve flight by name, or create it with the name, delayed, and arrival_time attributes...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(
    ['name' => 'Flight 10'],
    ['delayed' => 1, 'arrival_time' => '11:30']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with not exist in MYSQL, check Below

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1;
```